# Rules or legal requirements of using code from Stack Overflow

Tags: attribution

I am teaching a course on HTML, CSS, and JavaScript/jQuery. Recently the class I teach has had a few instances of Academic Dishonesty, so I am putting together a little segment to tell the students of my classes what they can and cannot do. I have discussed with them how on certain sites like CodePen there is a license that allows them to use code they find on there with attribution. A question came up about Stack Overflow, and I really don't know what the policy is here. I've searched the topic and looked in the Help Center but cannot find the issue addressed anywhere (if it is somewhere on the site and I've missed it, can you point me to it?).

So: If a person on here asks a question and someone provides an answer with a code snippet, does the person asking have to provide attribution to the answerer? Does it matter whether the snippet is 2 lines (would seem a bit ridiculous) or 50 lines? Does the answerer have to ask for attribution? What about someone who searches the site and finds the code in someone else's post? Does that third person have to provide attribution? Is there anything else I should know and tell the students about using code from Stack Overflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) info, it seems to be CC (but posts are linked to the CC version that was active/current at that time). Please check [this post as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347758/creative-commons-licensing-ui-and-data-updates).

As you can see on the info page, you can use the [Timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316) to check what version of the CC license applies.